# Create dictionary conditionally based on separate dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, dictionary, jupyter-notebook

I found similar questions but most are for Python 2 and earlier.

I have a column with 5000+ values and I am creating a dictionary out of it. I want to list out some rows with certain words and if the value doesn't contain it, it will be saved to 'Others'.

I have done the following:

```
my_groups = {
    'Group 1' : r'utilities|cleaning',
    'Group 2' : r'cooking|kitchen',
    'Group 3' : r'decorations|planning',
    'Group 4' : r'conceirge|guest|information|attendants',
    #...there are 300 groups in the dataset
}
```

But since the data is so large, I need to divide the groups into 2 categories: **frontline** and **backdoor**. I can do:

```
group_cat = {
    'Frontline' : r'conceirge|guest|information|attendants|waiter|MC',
    'Backdoor' : r'utilities|cleaning|cooking|kitchen|chef|event|decorations|planning',
    #...there are 300 groups in the dataset
}
```

But the list will be so long since there are around 300 groups with different descriptions. Is there a way that I can just specify the first one and assign other else automatically in the other?

```
#something like this
group_cat = {
    'Frontline' : r'conceirge|guest|information|attendants|waiter|MC',
    'Backdoor' : r'OTHER_KEYWORDS_HERE',
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly, the following code should work:

### Code:

```
my_groups = {
    'Group 1' : r'utilities|cleaning',
    'Group 2' : r'cooking|kitchen',
    'Group 3' : r'decorations|planning',
    'Group 4' : r'conceirge|guest|information|attendants',
}

group_cat = {
    'Frontline' : r'conceirge|guest|information|attendants|waiter|MC'
    }

group_cat['Backdoor'] = '|'.join(set(x 
                                     for val in my_groups.values()
                                     for x in val.split('|') 
                                     if x not in group_cat['Frontline'])
                                 )
```

### Output:

```
>>> group_cat
{'Frontline': 'conceirge|guest|information|attendants|waiter|MC',
 'Backdoor': 'cooking|utilities|planning|cleaning|decorations|kitchen'}
```